# Advice for dealing with a metagaming player.

Tags: dnd-5e, problem-players, metagaming

This is my first post here, so bear with me.

I've been running a dnd group with some friends over the past couple months. Doing some one off adventures to start but have lately been doing a full campaign.

One of my players has a tendency to meta game, but not in the traditional sense. Perhaps I'm worrying over nothing and his way of meta gaming is common, but he actively in character knows his own stats and levels.

It makes sense that if you have an 18 in strength your character is probably confident in their physical abilities, but it goes beyond that.

There's an issue that whenever I present a challenge or encounter and my players are making a plan this one player always decides no matter what to **charge in and attack**.

Initially there's no problem with this, but it can get problematic. Let's use an example that say there a a group of 5 or 6 orcs and you are level 10 or 11, you as a player know that the numbers on your sheet are high enough to mop the floor with them and that their CR isn't high so it'll be as easy as that. That's my problem, I think that way of thinking is technically meta gaming atleast in my eyes.

I even tried to subtly explain it to the player using the same example but he wasn't having any of it.

Out of all my players they are the biggest issue. Meta gaming and a god complex are not a good combo.

Anyway thanks for reading my novel of a question.

Any advice is appreciated. It's not like I want this player gone it's just I feel he is sometimes ruining the game for the others.

Comment: I dont quite understand the problem. You're saying you dont want him to be so brave? or to just not attack monsters based on their CR? Does he actively run away from anything higher than his level?

Comment: Agree with Nemenia that not entirely sure I see the problem. If a character has encountered a particular creature before its not unreasonable to assume they would know they could beat them (of course, they may know orcs but not be expecting an orc chief or shaman...)

Comment: It's assumed that a character knows their capabilities. Surely a level 10 or 11 character has been killing orcs for ages, so where exactly does the metagaming come in? I don't see how this question makes sense unless the character would have no idea of knowing what an orc is.

Comment: I'm not sure I see a *question* anywhere in there. Is it, "How do I make my world feel dangerous as levels increase?" Is it, "How do I get this player to act like his character is mortal?" Is it, "How do I keep a player from making reference to gaming terms in the fiction?" Is it something else I've totally missed?

Comment: You mention this player ruining it for the other players. How so? What are they saying about it? What's the problem from their perspective?

Comment: I hope your example is only a poorly considered hypothetical, and not a real example from your campaign, because five or six orcs would be be only a medium challenge for even a lone level 10 character, and trivial for a party of such characters, and an experienced adventurer will know this. If I ask you to perform a routine task in the real world I'd sound crazy to attribute your confidence in completing it to some kind of metaknowledge: you know what the limits of your skills are and can determine when a task is easily within those limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem a lot of times (if I understand correctly) with a few players in my time as a GM.

I assume your player is the typical 'rush to the enemy and kill them all' type and you want them (the whole group) to make a strategy and do tactics to win the confrontation.

If this is the case, my recommendation (works for me all time) is providing more challenging confrontations that can't be won with front/rush combat. In other words, try to show them with a visual explanation of the situation that a frontal attack to the enemies will be an absolute failure and that they would need to use their heads to think of a solution to overcome the enemies.

You can use the scenario: terrain (like a bridge, walls, etc.), types of enemies (like PJRZ said) like spellcasters or big monsters, the weather, etc. Use your imagination, having the *modus operandi* of that player in mind at all times.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

## Turn up the challenge

He rushes alone every time?  Let him face something that can hurt him really bad.
Make his life difficult if he keeps soloing.  Let him take some debuffs (traps or spells that lower his Stats -- shadows drain strength with a hit, for example).   Let him sense the death of his PC around the next corner, he will try to cooperate more :)